# Color row(s) in a table to Green wherever value in a row/column intersection is 'Yes" in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to color all rows in an excel table where the row value for foo column is 'Yes'

Eg -

Table1

```
    A     B     C
1   NO    5     6
2  Yes    1     2 
3   NO    4     6
4  Yes    6     5
```

Rows 2 & 3 of Table 1 should be colored green

Comment: You can do this without VBA using Conditional Formatting. Go to "Highlight Cells Rules" -> "Use a formula to determine which cells to format". Then add a formula like this: =$A1="Yes". Copy the formatting to the entire table.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Paul, but I need to automate this and hence need to do it through VBA